# Python - Best way to count IPs that fall under IP range

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip

I have a python script that grabs all IP from the arp table and assign it to a variable.  I have for loop that creates another two variables start_IP containing the first IP of a subnet and last_IP containing the last IP in that same subnet.  For each loop I will have a different start and last IPs.

I am trying to do check the variable containing all IPs and see how many IPs fall under each subnet.

What would be the best way to do this?  Here is a hardcoded example:
count = 0

```
arps = ['10.20.30.130','10.20.30.131','10.20.30.132', '10.20.30.133', 
'10.20.30.136', '10.20.30.137', '10.20.30.138', '10.20.30.139', '10.20.30.140', '10.20.30.141', '10.20.30.143', '10.20.30.149']
 start_ip = "10.20.30.132"
 end_ip = "10.20.30.142"
 count = 0      
 for arp in arps:
    if arp >= start_ip and arp <= end_ip:
        count = count + 1
        print count
    else:
        continue

 print "Count: ", count
```

Is there a better an faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two solutions as below. Method 1 has a time complexity of `O(N)` and Method 2 has a time complexity of `O(Nlog N)`. As suggested by Amadan, the IP addresses need to be preprocessed beforehand.

```
import bisect

arps = ['10.20.30.130','10.20.30.131','10.20.30.132', '10.20.30.133', 
'10.20.30.136', '10.20.30.137', '10.20.30.138', '10.20.30.139', '10.20.30.140', '10.20.30.141', '10.20.30.143', '10.20.30.149']
start_ip = "10.20.30.132"
end_ip = "10.20.30.142"

# Padding zeros to the IP addresses to make sure they are directly comparable
def padding(s):
    return s.zfill(3)

arps = [".".join(list(map(padding, x.split(".")))) for x in arps]
start_ip = ".".join(list(map(padding, start_ip.split("."))))
end_ip   = ".".join(list(map(padding, end_ip.split("."))))

# Method 1: Pythonic one-liner
print(sum(start_ip <= x <= end_ip for x in arps))

# Method 2: Sort and binary search
def find_lt(a, x):
    i = bisect.bisect_right(a, x)
    if i:
        return i - 1
    else:
        return 0

def find_gt(a, x):
    i = bisect.bisect_right(a, x)
    if i != len(a):
        return i
    else:
        return i

arps.sort()
print(find_gt(arps, end_ip) - find_lt(arps, start_ip))
```

Comment: This is not correct, due to the issue I explain in my answer - `sort` will not sort string-IPs in the right order.

Comment: @Amadan Yeah, you are right. Let me show a workaround.

Comment: Also, the Method 2 has complexity of O(log N) if you ignore the fact that you sort them. Sort itself is O(N log N). (Of course, big-O is not a measure of speed, just complexity...)

Comment: @Amadan True. Thanks. How about now?

Comment: It'll work, though I think `list(map(int, x.split(".")))` is much simpler and faster than `".".join(list(map(padding, x.split("."))))`.

Comment: Agree. I intended to keep some meaningful forms, which may or may not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will give it a try and see what works best for me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Method 1 worked for me.  Is there any way I can also add a print for all matched IPs?

Comment: `l = [x for x in arps if start_ip <= x <= end_ip]`
`print(l)`
`print(len(l))`

Comment: Thanks!!!!!  That worked like a charm.  The zfill'd IP address is messing up the output and I am trying to find a way to remove leading 0s.  I need to perform further actions on the IP so when they are zfill'd they fail.  I do want to keep the 0 in cse an octet only has 0.  Example:  10.0.10.0

Comment: Say you have an IP string `a`. Then you can do `".".join([x.lstrip('0') or '0' for x in a.split(".")])`.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways. The simple way:

IP addresses compare octet-by-octet. Interestingly, Python lists compare element-by-element. So if you just split the IP addresses by dot and map the list to `int`, you can compare them correctly.

The even simpler way:

`ipaddress.ip_address` is comparable, as long the compared addresses are the same version (IPv4 or IPv6).

However, string comparison does not provide a correct ordering of IP addresses:

```
'1.12.1.1' < '1.2.1.1'
# => True (should be False)
```

Except for those issues, your code is fine. It could be written more concisely:

```
import ipaddress
arps = ['10.20.30.130','10.20.30.131','10.20.30.132', '10.20.30.133', 
    '10.20.30.136', '10.20.30.137', '10.20.30.138', '10.20.30.139', 
    '10.20.30.140', '10.20.30.141', '10.20.30.143', '10.20.30.149']
start_ip = "10.20.30.132"
end_ip = "10.20.30.142"

start_ip_ip = ipaddress.ip_address(start_ip)
end_ip_ip = ipaddress.ip_address(end_ip)

sum(1 for ip in arps if start_ip_ip <= ipaddress.ip_address(ip) <= end_ip_ip)
# => 8
```

If you specifically want to see addresses in specific subnet, you don't even need to use start and end addresses, if you know the subnet specification:

```
ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.17') in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/16')
# => True
```

Comment: I do have CIDR in my database so your last solution might work perfect and minimize code.  I will give it a try!  Thanks

Comment: I am going to use the first solution.  I am using python 2 so I had to convert all IP strings to Unicode first to make it work.